# What is this VIM plugin?

Tags: vim, vimrc

It's a modified vim bar that includes current path and current git branch. I've been looking around but couldn't find anything.

[image]

[image]

Found in: https://github.com/w0ng/vim-hybrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called vim-powerline or [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline). If you look in [w0ng's vimrc](https://github.com/w0ng/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) you can see it listed in there:

*excerpt*

```
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
" https://github.com/*
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'
Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplcache'
Bundle 'godlygeek/tabular'
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Bundle 'mileszs/ack.vim.git'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
Bundle 'w0ng/vim-github-theme'
Bundle 'w0ng/vim-hybrid'
```

Comment: The `Bundle` command won't work in a vimrc on plain vim, it's provided by [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) (also included in the list of bundles above).

Comment: @Wieland - thanks, I wasn't showing him how to add it, just how to see what plugin w0ng was using to get that functionality.